# netsh advfirewall => command not found

Tags: windows-vista, java, netbeans, windows-firewall, netsh

Because of the [Java 7 firewall problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6990663/java-7-prevents-ftp-transfers-on-windows-vista-and-7-if-firewall-is-on-any-idea), I am trying to execute the following command as administrator but I get an error:

```
netsh advfirewall set global StatefulFTP disable
```

> (German) "Der folgende Befehl wurde nicht gefunden: advfirewall"

In English, something like:

> "The following command was not found: advfirewall"

I found a [related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943862/netsh-mbn-show-interfaces-results-in-command-not-found-on-win7-64bit), but I am not running Windows 64bit; I am using Windows Vista Business SP2 32bit.

A workaround is to disable the firewall, but that is not a good solution.

According to the [Sun bug report](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7077696), it is possible to change the firewall setting over the registry but I don't know how.

Any ideas?

**Update**

In the [Microsoft documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778925%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) about netsh I found an article describing my error message. It explains that depending on the installation different contexts are available. I don't have the "netsh advfirewall" context on two different computers.

Comment: are you running the netsh command from CMD or from inside a Java Program?

Comment: from cmd started with "Run as Administrator"

Comment: is the advanced firewall control panel available to you?

Comment: You mean the one in the managment console? Yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may have an **unregistered or missing helper dll** within netsh

Run `netsh show helper` from and administrator command prompt and scan the output for the advfirewall context. If it is missing, run `netsh add helper AUTHFWCFG.DLL` to restore it.

---

### Full list of netsh helpers (contexts) you may want to register

advfirewall: `netsh add helper  AUTHFWCFG.DLL` 
firewall: `netsh add helper  FWCFG.DLL`
http: `netsh add helper  NSHHTTP.DLL`
interface: `netsh add helper  IFMON.DLL`
bridge: `netsh add helper  HNETMON.DLL`
dhcpclient: `netsh add helper  DHCPCMONITOR.DLL`
dnsclient, netio: `netsh add helper  NETIOHLP.DLL`
ipsec: `netsh add helper  NSHIPSEC.DLL`
lan: `netsh add helper  DOT3CFG.DLL`
mbn: `netsh add helper  WWANCFG.DLL`
namespace: `netsh add helper  NETIOHLP.DLL`
nap: `netsh add helper  NAPMONTR.DLL`
p2p: `netsh add helper  P2PNETSH.DLL`
ras: `netsh add helper  RASMONTR.DLL`
rpc: `netsh add helper  RPCNSH.DLL`
trace: `netsh add helper  NETTRACE.DLL`
wcn: `netsh add helper  WCNNETSH.DLL`
wfp: `netsh add helper  NSHWFP.DLL`
winhttp: `netsh add helper  WHHELPER.DLL`
winsock: `netsh add helper  WSHELPER.DLL`
wlan: `netsh add helper  WLANCFG.DLL`

Comment: In Windows 11, `netsh add helper AUTHFWCFG.DLL` yields the error `Initialization Function InitHelperDll in AUTHFWCFG.DLL failed to start with error code 15018`

Answer (score 1):

**You may need to run this with elevated privileges** *as administrator*

---

### How can I do that?

Use one of the following methods:

- [Open an Elevated Command Prompt in Six Keystrokes](http://blogs.msdn.com/tims/archive/2006/11/02/windows-vista-secret-10-open-an-elevated-command-prompt-in-six-keystrokes.aspx) 
   Press <kbd>Win</kbd> type `cmd` <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and then hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to confirm the elevation prompt.
- [Install an Elevation Container](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/03/27/elevate-a-process-at-the-command-line-in-vista.aspx)
   Download John Robbins' excellent program `elevate.exe` and place it in your path. Now you can call programs with elevated privileges using `elevate <program> <program arguments>` <sub>(or you can rename it sudo.exe and call them with `sudo`)</sub>
- [Scripting Elevation](http://blogs.msdn.com/aaron_margosis/archive/2007/07/01/scripting-elevation-on-vista.aspx)

### Why is this necessary?

According to [Netsh Commands for Windows Firewall with Advanced Security](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771920(v=WS.10).aspx) *you must have the required permissions to run the netsh advfirewall commands*.

- If you are a member of the Administrators group, and User Account Control is enabled on your computer, then run the commands from a command prompt with elevated permissions. To start a command prompt with elevated permissions, find the icon or Start menu entry that you use to start a command prompt session, right-click it, and then click Run as administrator.
- If you are a member of the Network Operators group then you can run the commands from any command prompt.
- If you are a not a member of Administrators or Network Operators, and have not been delegated any other permissions to run this command, then you can run only those commands that display, but do not change settings.

Comment: Thank you, I have elevated rights using the first method. Same problem.