# netsh advfirewall command was not found

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, windows-firewall, netsh

I have an advanced rule setup in Windows firewall that I want to be able to turn on and off via an AutoHotkey script.

```
RunWaitOne(command) {
    shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
    exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C " command)
    return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}

!d::
    if WinActive("ahk_exe Hearthstone.exe")
        RunWaitOne("netsh advfirewall set rule name=hearthstone new enable=yes")
        Sleep, 1000  ; 1000ms of delay between disconnecting and reconnecting
        RunWaitOne("netsh advfirewall set rule name=hearthstone new enable=no") 
    return
```

The rule works fine manually when I turn it on and off via the pannel however when testing the script and the action manually I get an error: *The following command was not found: advfirewall set rule name=hearthstone new enable=yes.*

This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/430414/netsh-advfirewall-command-not-found) suggested it was a missing helper however when I ran `netsh show helper` the .DLL for advfirewall is present so I'm rather at a loss on how to further debug this.

EDIT: Yes I have AHK running with elevated privileges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue wasn't with the need to simplify the script. There was a missing command in the chain.

It was missing a `firewall` in the [RunWait command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm).

The correct code that works is:

```
RunWaitOne(command) {
shell := ComObjCreate("WScript.Shell")
exec := shell.Exec(ComSpec " /C " command)
return exec.StdOut.ReadAll()
}

!d::
    if WinActive("ahk_exe Hearthstone.exe")
        RunWaitOne("netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=hearthstone new enable=yes")
        Sleep, 1000  ; 1000ms of delay between disconnecting and reconnecting
        RunWaitOne("netsh advfirewall firewall set rule name=hearthstone new enable=no") 
    return
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a missing helper - you are executing the whole command-string as the
command-name. There is no executable whose name is this entire string
"netsh advfirewall set rule...".

I suggest to simplify the script by using the
[RunWait command](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)
instead of `ComObjCreate`.

Your command may then look like this:

```
!d::
if WinActive("ahk_exe Hearthstone.exe")
    RunWait, %comspec% /c netsh advfirewall set rule name=hearthstone new enable=yes,,hide
    Sleep, 1000  ; 1000ms of delay between disconnecting and reconnecting
    RunWait, %comspec% /c netsh advfirewall set rule name=hearthstone new enable=no,,hide
return
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how this would fit into the code above? Maybe add it to your answer? I tried replacing the top part with your code but nothing happens when I try and execute the script.

Comment: I've fleshed out the AHK code, replacing the RunWaitOne part. The rest of the code is yours without change.

Comment: Unfortunately this is incorrect.

Comment: What is incorrect here? And why use ComObjCreate when AHK does it for you?